# Android Google Plus API: Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson() returns null

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to integrate google+ sign in in an Android application. The API is connecting and the sign in also works. But unfortunately i am unable to retrieve users profile info. I have put 2 SHA1 key on the developer console. One is using the Android's SDK's debug.keystore file and another is from project keystore files which has been generated in Android Studio.

GoogleApiClient has been setup like this:

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

onConnection method:

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    signedInUser = false;

    //Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            username.setText(personName);
            emailLabel.setText(email);                
        }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml permission:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

build.gradle(app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

..........
..........
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
 compile files('libs/android_adcolony_2.2.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
 compile files('libs/heyzap-ads-sdk.jar')
 compile files('libs/android_unityads_4.0.1.jar')
}
```

I followed the official google+ api documentation regarding setting the configuration files and the SHA1 hashkey generation using keytool.

Logcat:

```
10-19 13:06:36.961  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
10-19 13:06:36.971  5859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities E/Zygote﹕ v2
10-19 13:06:36.971  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10272
10-19 13:06:36.971  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G920I_5.0.2 ver=22
10-19 13:06:36.971  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
10-19 13:06:36.971  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G920I_5.1.1_0035
10-19 13:06:36.971  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities E/Zygote﹕ accessInfo : 0
10-19 13:06:36.971  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL 
10-19 13:06:37.021  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
10-19 13:06:37.021  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
10-19 13:06:37.091  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
10-19 13:06:37.111  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath caller
10-19 13:06:37.151  25859-25880/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
10-19 13:06:37.151  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/InjectionManager﹕ InjectionManager
10-19 13:06:37.151  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/InjectionManager﹕ fillFeatureStoreMap com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities
10-19 13:06:37.151  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/InjectionManager﹕ Constructor com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities, Feature store :{}
10-19 13:06:37.151  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/InjectionManager﹕ featureStore :{}
10-19 13:06:37.161  25859-25880/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
10-19 13:06:37.161  25859-25880/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
10-19 13:06:37.161  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-19 13:06:37.181  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
10-19 13:06:37.181  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
10-19 13:06:37.201  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath caller
10-19 13:06:37.201  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
10-19 13:06:37.201  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
10-19 13:06:37.271  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call Injection manager
10-19 13:06:37.271  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/InjectionManager﹕ dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities.TestActivity isFragment :false
10-19 13:06:37.281  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-19 13:06:37.291  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
10-19 13:06:37.291  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/PhoneWindow﹕ *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
10-19 13:06:37.321  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
10-19 13:06:37.341  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
10-19 13:06:37.361  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-19 13:06:37.371  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f761bfec0 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 1982403248
10-19 13:06:37.371  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
10-19 13:06:37.371  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-19 13:06:37.371  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
10-19 13:06:37.471  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@324ea6d time:3900228
10-19 13:06:38.441  25859-25859/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/SRIB_DCS﹕ log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
10-19 13:06:38.441  25859-25889/com.littlefroginc.rollnearn.android.activities D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [497x181]-format:1
```

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your GoogleApiClient like this:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .build();
```

and if you dont have the below code in your manifest, then add it in side the application tag

```
<application>
.
.
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
.
.
</application>
```

Comment: Same results. Login works but cant retrieve the profile.

Comment: "Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)" - this returns null?

Comment: and how are you saying Login works? Is that because this toast (Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();) displays?

Comment: Hari: yes its returns null. My mistake about login, actually i thought it works by seeing connect message in Toast.

Comment: there is an edit in my answer. please read it and tell me the result.

Comment: Added , same result. I will now try the google+ sample project. See if that works.

Comment: So after running the google+ sign in example app i get the following message:
`10-19 14:19:38.591  21951-21951/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin D/MainActivity﹕ onConnected:null
 10-19 14:19:38.591  21951-21951/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin W/MainActivity﹕ Error: Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson returned null. Ensure that the Google+ API is enabled for your project, you have a properly configured google-services.json file and that your device has an internet connection. `

Comment: Ok, then, open your project in the console and inside the API&auths -> APIs -> Enable APIs-> Google+API , please check that Google+ API is enabled or not.

Comment: Can you log what you got as "Bundle arg0" in your onConnected method. Please tell me what that logs.

Comment: are you calling the  mGoogleApiClient.connect(); on the same mGoogleApiClient that you defined first? Can you make that sure? Or can you provide the code where you call mGoogleApiClient.connect() ?

Comment: Ok so i finally made it able to work. Problem was that in the developer console i have added wrong package name for my project. Now its finally working. Thanks all for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code its working for me

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

ang get email as

```
String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```